# FileUpload content is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I know there's many questions about the same topic, but I haven't see one that addresses my issue. So I have an `UpdatePanel` in it's `ContentTemplate` I have a `ListView` with a `Panel`, inside it is there's a `FileUpload`, a Cancel  button and an Upload button. When Upload button is pressed it calls a method, on the server side, that handles the file uploading business. My problem is that the `HttpFileCollection` object is empty even though I did pick something.

This is an example of what I'm doing. Do to the company's policy I can't post the original programming, but this should be enough cause it's the only things running when uploading.

Client side:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMain" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:ListView>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlFileUpload" runat="server" CssClass ="custom-menu">
            <asp:FileUpload ID="fuUpload" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="OnUploadFile" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />                                    
        </asp:Panel>

        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeUpload" runat="server" TargetControlID ="imgBtnUploadFile" PopupControlID="pnlFileUpload" CancelControlID="btnCancel"
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackgroud">
            <Animations>
            <OnShown>
                <%--The FadeIn and Display animation.--%>
                <FadeIn Duration="0.25" MinimumOpacity="0" MaximumOpacity="1" />
            </OnShown>
            </Animations>
        </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
    </asp:ListView>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Server side:

```
protected void OnUploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpFileCollection files = Request.Files; 
}
```

I have a break point on `files` and when it hits, the `keys` are 0,  the `content` is empty and so is the `InputStream`. I've tried a few different things from setting the page's `enctype ="multipart/form-data"` to many other things I can't remember, right now.

Still getting the hang of asp so any suggestions with **explanation**, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try placing it outside of the `UpdatePanel`, some times the `UpdatePanel` will do a `Post` without you knowing it via Ajax.  Then, the file that was there vanishes because though it shows the file, but when you do the `Post` the control is unaware of the file.

Comment: @Greg, That makes sense. I'll try something out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is more than likely due to your `UpdatePanel`.  The premise of the Control is wonderful, sadly the execution is down right terrible.  It often can create issues with your *Page State*.    It does this in how the `UpdatePanel` actually works.

The Control will take a copy of your page, store it in memory, and then it will reload your page in entirety.  Which will impede your performance, but a side effect is when the page is reloaded, it will go through *Asp.Net Page Life Cycle*.  Which can create a slew of issues if you aren't careful.

What I would do, would be move your `FileUpload` and `Upload Button` out of the panel, verify that it is uploading correctly.  Once you confirm that, you know the *UpdatePanel* is the culprit.  Then you can work within the constraints, or I would do manual Ajax Request.

Hopefully this explanation is in more detail for you.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I'll try to organize things. I'll probably mark this one as answer.

Comment: I have another issue, sorry. Once the file is selected and goes to `OnUploadFile` the `HttpFileCollection ` says it has something but the `InputStream` is empty.

Comment: Why complicate it, do the check once you hit a button and see if it has a file.  Unless you really need to do those checks during that event.

Comment: I made it work, I switched back to using the `FileUpload` object instead of `HttpFileCollection `. Thanks

Comment: I believe the object actually uses an octet-array, which is easy to work with.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454%28v=vs.140%29.aspx):

> The following ASP.NET controls are **not compatible** with partial-page
>   updates, and are therefore not designed to work inside an **UpdatePanel**
>   control:
>
> ...
>
> **FileUpload** and HtmlInputFile controls when they are used to upload
>   files as part of an **asynchronous postback**.
>   ...
>
> To use a **FileUpload** or HtmlInputFile control inside an **UpdatePanel**
>   control, set the **postback** control that submits the file to be a
>   **PostBackTrigger** control for the panel. The **FileUpload** and
>   HtmlInputFile control **can be used only in postback scenarios**.

Comment: Funny thing is that it worked on an early version of my web app on chrome but not on ie9 and I had something very similar to what I showed here.